# gluon-mobile plugin cannot handle multi-release jars

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

Deploying one of my example JavaFX applications to an Android device via the gluon-mobile Eclipse plugin fails with an IllegalArgumentException in the retrolambda plugin. This is caused by an indirect dependency of my project on jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar which is a multi-release jar. Retrolambda obviously cannot handle the Java 9 parts in this file and instead of just ignoring them throws an exception. How can this be fixed or avoided?

A newer version of retrolambda (2.5.3 instead of 2.5.1) can handle the module-info.class already but not the part in the META-INF/versions/9/...
The problem could be cured by just deleting the META-INF stuff but when I do that manually it is always re-created by the gluon plugin.

Update 1:

Adding

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude '/META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class'
    }
```

to the android section in the build file does not make any difference. The error message is still the same:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:185)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:168)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.ClassAnalyzer.analyze(ClassAnalyzer.java:25)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda$1.visitClass(Retrolambda.java:71)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:29)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.files.ClasspathVisitor.visitFile(ClasspathVisitor.java:11)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.visitFiles(Retrolambda.java:107)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:68)
at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

This can also be verified easily by just running the command line version of retrlambda over the extracted classes of jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar

Update 2:

With Java 9 and the Gluon-VM it fails with:

```
Execution failed for task ':SingleViewProject - Gluon VMApp:apkDebug'.
> Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK: META-INF/LICENSE.txt
  File 1: /Users/mpaus/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.6.1/commons-math3-3.6.1.jar
  File 2: /Users/mpaus/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
```

Comment: Have you tried excluding the file with `android { packagingOptions { exclude 'META-INF/versions/9/...' } }`?

Comment: Please see my update above.

Comment: This issue has been handled for Java 9 projects on mobile with Gluon VM (still under developer preview). You can give it a try with the template 'single view project with Gluon VM'. If you stick to Java 8, can you try `jaxb-api-2.2.12`?

Comment: See update 2 above. I cannot easily switch to the older jaxb-api because it is an external dependency. Would the Gluon-VM approach also work with Java 10 because that is what I am normally using?

Comment: You have duplicated files, and you can solve that easily with `exclude`, as many times as you need to. Gluon VM should work with 10 as well

Comment: Ok, so it works with Java 9 and the exclude statements but switching to Java 10 gives me: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Gluon VM requires Java 9, but Java 10 was detected.

Comment: Use the latest jfxmobile version (2.0.20), it should fix that issue.

Comment: Great, that worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad that it did. If you want I can write a formal answer, as it might be useful for others as well?

Comment: Yes, that might be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I posted my answer. Note also that I figured out how to modify the current jfxmobile plugin 1.3.10 to allow multirelease jars. But it is more convenient using the new one 2.0.20 if you can switch to Gluon VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar` is a multi-release jar and the current jfxmobile plugin 1.3.10 can't deal with it.

The plugin, that targets Java 7/8, uses retrolambda to port back to Java 6/7 a given dependency.

Even if you try to remove the `module-info.class or the 9 version`META-INF.versions.9.javax.xml.bind`, these classes are processed by the retrolambda plugin, and this will lead to the exception posted in the question. Using the latest retrolambda version doesn't help either.

```
android {
    retrolambdaVersion = "2.5.3"
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude '/module-info.class'
        exclude '/META-INF.versions.9.javax.xml.bind/ModuleUtil.class'
    }
}
```

The only way to make it work under Java 8/jfxmobile 1.3.10 is by modifying the plugin, to add the following exception to [`JFXMobilePlugin`](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/a52bf6d2d124823875357c52cb7aa727e7993b36/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/JFXMobilePlugin.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#JFXMobilePlugin.groovy-393):

```
copyClassesForRetrolambda.include '**/*.class'
copyClassesForRetrolambda.includeEmptyDirs = false
// exception for multi-release jars    
copyClassesForRetrolambda.exclude 'META-INF/versions/**/*.class'
copyClassesForRetrolambda.exclude 'module-info.class'
```

and then build the plugin and use a local snapshot.

The good news is that using the jfxmobile plugin version 2.0.20 and Gluon VM, that targets Java 9+, the above is already [included](https://github.com/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/JFXMobilePlugin.groovy#L419).

If you can switch to Java 9/10, modify your project to use this plugin, create a new project with the Gluon IDE plugin ('single view project with Gluon VM'), or follow this [sample](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/singleview-gluonvm), but using the latest version (2.0.20 so far).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:2.0.20'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = '...'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0-jdk9'
    androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
}
```